# Limit of expression with increasing exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, exponential-function

I got stuck trying to evaluate:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1}\right) + \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1}\right)^3 + \dots + \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1}\right)^n    $$

I'd be grateful if you gave me some tips.

Comment: Have you tried using

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k} = \frac{1}{1-x} \quad \lvert x \rvert < 1$$

?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1}<1$ and you have a geometric progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $$\sum_0^N x^n= \frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}$$